# Go: is it possible to marshal a cycled json

Tags: json, go

I'm coding Go to create a Circular Singly Linked List: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/circular-singly-linked-list-insertion/

Here is my code:

```
type Node struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Next *Node  `json:"next"`
}

func main() {
    n1 := Node{Name: "111", Next: nil}
    n2 := Node{Name: "222", Next: &n1}
    n3 := Node{Name: "333", Next: &n2}
    n1.Next = &n3
}
```

However, when I try to marshal, I get an error: `json: unsupported value: encountered a cycle via *main.Node`

```
res, err := json.Marshal(n1)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
} else {
    fmt.Println(res)
}
```

Well, I understand why I get this error. So I want to know if there is some method to allow me to convert the struct of `Node` to JSON.

Comment: How would the JSON value look like? It would have to be infinite.

Comment: @Henry I understand. But when I code, it would be very helpful if I can marshal any object of `Node`, for example, I may need to log it or print it. If it can't be marshalled, what could I do? log or print it field by field? If the struct is nested and huge...

Comment: Define reference values for your JSON document type. Example: add unique string ID field to `Node`. Marshal `Node.Next` as the ID of the target node.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation of encoding/json.Marshal

> JSON cannot represent cyclic data structures and Marshal does not handle them. Passing cyclic structures to Marshal will result in an error.

The main part is "JSON cannot represent cyclic data structures" so the answer is a clear  No: It is not *possible* to have JSON which represents your value. You must redesign.

Comment: JSON's tree structure cannot represent cycles, but that does not mean that cycles cannot be represented in JSON. . Here's an example of a two node circular linked list: `[{"id": 1, "name": "foo", "next": 2}, {"id": 2, "name": "bar", "next": 1}]`.

Comment: @blunder You argument is flawed. If it would be valid I could say that the following JSON also represents a two node circular linked list: `"jkew7fhlskdncjken26fiuohskw9dkcn"`. Of course you can find a finite length representation of a circular data structure and encode that representation in some more (your  example) or less (mine) natural/understandable way into valid JSON, but that is some _custom_ encoding. You even could enumerate _all_ linked list and just send that number (think of some kind of Gödel-numbering the linked lists); but pay attention: numbers might get large.

Comment: Are you saying that the example document is not JSON, but is some *custom* thing that's not JSON?  It looks like JSON to me.  I don't think it's possible to enumerate all linked lists.

Comment: @blunder Your example is valid JSON. My example is valid JSON. I never implied that it is not JSON. My argument is not about valid or not valid JSON it is about (natural) representation and that there _are_ no _natural_ representations of circular data structures in JSON and any custom representation is well, just that: custom.

Comment: @blunder "I don't think it's possible to enumerate all linked lists." An astonishingly large class of things can be enumerated, that enumeration might be tricky or even unpractically tricky but that is not the meaning of  impossible.